# Active Admin Has One Polymorphic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations, formtastic

I am trying setup a select menu to associate a ImageGallery with a product. The ImageGallery is polymorphic since it is shared among a few models. Formtastic seems to be very confused about what to do. It is trying to call a method called Galleryable, the name of my polymorphic association, _id (galleryable_id) on the product model.

Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image_gallery, as: :galleryable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_gallery, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Gallery

```
class ImageGallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :galleryable, polymorphic: true

  validates :title, presence: true

  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: lambda { |t| t['file'].nil? }

end
```

Active Admin form

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :category
      f.input :price
      f.input :purchase_path
      f.input :video_panels
      f.input :image_panels
      f.input :image_gallery, :as => :select, collection: ImageGallery.all, value_method: :id
    end
    f.inputs "Image", :for => [:image, f.object.image || Image.new] do |i|
      i.input :title
      i.input :file, :as => :file, required: false, :hint => i.template.image_tag(i.object.file.url(:thumb))
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

I played with defining galleryable_id on the model, but this tries to update the product with the attribute which of course does not exist.

Has anyone successfully set this up?

Thanks,

Cory

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one answered because it is quite an interesting scenario.

You almost got it but you nested your relationships wrongly in your AA form. The following should work instead:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :category
    f.input :price
    f.input :purchase_path
    f.input :video_panels
    f.input :image_panels
    f.inputs "ImageGallery", :for => [:image_gallery, f.object.image_gallery || ImageGallery.new] do |gallery|
      gallery.has_many :images do |image|
        image.input :title
        image.input :file, :as => :file, required: false, :hint => image.template.image_tag(image.object.file.url(:thumb))
      end
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

This will tie an "ImageGallery" to your product. An has_one relationship can't be passed directly to your parent model (as you were trying to do with `f.input :image_gallery`).

Hope it helped :)